adding drain from 2nd floor to 1st floor sink drain?
Want to add a washing machine drain on the 2nd floor, closest drain will be a sink on the first floor. It is also not possible adding a vent to the ceiling.

Question:

Is what the image shown possible?
Should I add a air admittance valve under the 1st floor sink? What about 2nd floor?
I should use a sanitary tee as the joint?
Where should I install p trap for new drain? on 2nd floor(1), below the joist(2), next to the sink (3)?
Thanks for help


It may depend on your local plumbing code, but personally—if unable to vent—I would put the P-trap and AAV at the washer.  How is the sink vented?

the sink had no AAV...It was added a while back, connected to the old main drain.  So I worried it might not have been done right. Plumbing code not my biggest concern, just how is it done

"P-trap and AAV at the washer“ so the P-trap at location 1? why do we do that? do we want the P-trap to be closet to the opening(ie. sink, washer drain pipe...)?

Well, if you put the trap for the washer down at the sink, and you get a clog at the trap, when you open the trap to drain it, you'll have a lot more water to drain than you would if your trap was located at the washer.

install the trap beside the washer means that it will be hidden inside the drywall, which defeat the purpose of easily maintain...if maintenance is the only catch, I will pick beside the sink
